# i18n language files. How to manage missing and unused keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, internationalization, static-analysis, i18n-tasks

I have a Rails/Angular webapp. We use two different methods to translate our app: [Ruby Globalize](https://github.com/globalize/globalize) i18n with the corresponding yml language files, and [angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) with the corresponding json language files. Managing language files can be a pain. I just found the [i18n-tasks gem on github](https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks) to help find missing and unused keys in my yml language files. It works great! Does anyone know of a similar static analysis tool to help manage json language files? Is there a better way to do this?

As I write this I am wondering if there is some sort of i18n transpilation that I could do. Keep a single language file and generate the yml and json from that.

Features wanted:

- sort keys alphabetically
- delete unused keys in all language files
- add missing keys in all language files

Answer (score 1):

i18n-tasks already supports JSON, but you would need to write a custom scanner to detect usages of angular-translate. See [the custom scanner example](https://github.com/glebm/i18n-tasks/wiki/A-custom-scanner-example).